# Configuring Authentication Header in Jersey API Client Side

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jersey

There is following way to  configure the authentication header in Jersey API .

```
//Universal builder having different credentials for different schemes

HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.universalBuilder()

.credentialsForBasic("username1", "password1")

.credentials("username2", "password2").build();



final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

client.register(feature);
```

But not able to figure out how to pass extra parameter to authentication header for e.g. IntegatorKey, SendBehalfOf.   those are specific REST service  call.

In My Case to call  REST service need to  pass following parameter as part of authentication header.

1. Username
2. Password
3. IntegatorKey
4. SendBehalfOf

How should I achieve this using the Jersey API ?

Comment: How do you need to send these additional parameters?

Comment: Not enough info. Please do some more research on what the API requires, and update your post to reflect these requirements in detail with proper terminology. Your post doesn't make much sense in its current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You didn't provide enough information in your question.* It's hard guessing what you are trying to achieve. You really should consider updating your question with more details.

---

Having a look at the superficial information you provided, I *guess* you are trying to access the [DocuSign REST API](https://www.docusign.co.uk/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3). If so, you could create a [`ClientRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html), as following:

```java
public class DocuSignAuthenticator implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String integatorKey;
    private String sendBehalfOf;

    public DocuSignAuthenticator(String username, String password, 
                                 String integatorKey, String sendBehalfOf) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.integatorKey = integatorKey;
        this.sendBehalfOf = sendBehalfOf;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add(
            "X-DocuSign-Authentication", getAuthenticationHeader());
    }

    private String getAuthenticationHeader() {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("<DocuSignCredentials>");

        builder.append("<SendOnBehalfOf>");
        builder.append(sendBehalfOf);
        builder.append("</SendOnBehalfOf>");

        builder.append("<Username>");
        builder.append(username);
        builder.append("</Username>");

        builder.append("<Password>");
        builder.append(password);
        builder.append("</Password>");

        builder.append("<IntegratorKey>");
        builder.append(integatorKey);
        builder.append("</IntegratorKey>");

        builder.append("</DocuSignCredentials>");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

And register it when creating a [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance:

```java
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(
        new DocuSignAuthenticator(username, password, integatorKey, sendBehalfOf));
```

Comment: I will try your approach

Comment: @Damajikalunge Please, consider providing more details in your question.

Comment: Which Authentication policy is it going to follow :    BASIC: 
    BASIC NON-PREEMPTIVE: 
    UNIVERSAL:

Comment: @Damajikalunge It's a custom authentication. Why don't you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to consume the DocuSign service using jersey API.